# Add DateTime offset in seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a DateTime in UTC, and would like add an offset which is provided in seconds

```
#json parsed - utc offset in seconds - turned into integer
@utc_offset = result["UTCOffsetMillis"].to_i
#json parsed - utc date
start_date_string = result["startDate"].split("-")
start_date = DateTime.new(start_date_string[0].to_i, start_date_string[1].to_i,start_date_string[2].to_i)
```

How do I add this offset in seconds to start_date??

Rails 3.2.3
Ruby 1.9.2p320

Answer (score 8):

To add an offset in seconds to a `DateTime` you can use:

```
DateTime.new(2012, 10, 31) + 5.seconds
#=> Wed, 31 Oct 2012 00:00:05 +0000
```

To change the *timezone*, I'd use `Time` instead of `DateTime`:

```
Time.new(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0, 3600).localtime
#=> 2014-10-31 00:00:00 +0100
```

`3600` is the offset from UTC in seconds.